# Travelling salesman problem with variable weights

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, traveling-salesman-problem

Take a fully connected graph with $v$ vertices. We assign weights to edges using an arbitrary function $f_{ij}(x)$ for pairs of vertices $0 < i, j \le v$, then starting at $c_{0}=0$, traverse the graph calculating each cost with $c_{n+1}=c_n + f_{ij}(c_n)$, with $n$ being the number of vertices previously visited. In essence, the weights are a function on the current cumulative cost.

Firstly, are there any better ways to represent this concept?

Secondly, are there any algorithms (beyond an exhaustive search) which can find the path which optimises the total cost $c_v$, visiting each vertice exactly once?

Thank you.

Comment: For general functions it's easy to make this problem as hard as inverting a hash function, so it's hopeless to approximate even a little bit without exhaustive search.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving If I knew about the properties of the functions (e.g. polynomials), are there approaches which would help to approximate?